# Showing the matrix 1-norm equals the maximum of a sum

Tags: matrices

I want to show:

$$\|A\|_{1} := \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{1}}{\|x\|_{1}} = \max_{1\leqslant j \leqslant n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$$

My attempt to show it directly by applying the definition of $\|A\|_{1}$ has failed several times. I'm looking for some useful tips and or hints. Many thanks.

Comment: $a_{ij}$ would be entries from the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that

$$ ||A||_1 = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_1}{||x||_1} = \max_{x \neq 0} \left| \left| A \left( \frac{x}{||x||_1} \right) \right| \right|_{1} = \max_{||y||_1 = 1} ||Ay||_1. $$

Denote the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $e_j$. Then $||e_j||_1 = 1$ and

$$ ||Ae_j||_1 = ||(a_{1j}, \ldots, a_{nj})^T||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|. $$

Thus, we have

$$ ||A||_1 \geq \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Ae_j||_1 = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|. $$

For the other direction, if $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $||y||_1 = 1$ then by the triangle inequality and the linearity we have

$$ ||Ay||_1 = \left| \left| A \left( \sum_{j=1}^n y_j e_j \right) \right| \right|_1 = \left| \left| \sum_{j=1}^n y_j A(e_j) \right| \right|_1 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j| \cdot ||Ae_j||_1 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |y_j| \cdot \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Ae_j||_1 = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Ae_j||_1 = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|. $$